# How can i have two separate web services with identical name space and local name requests be routed to different end points?

Tags: web-services, spring, spring-ws, spml

I'm attempting to create 2 separate web services, both within one spring deployment, both with the wsdl's being generated from the same xsd schemas, yet have them be routed to two separate end points so i can handle the requests differently in the separate contexts.

Ex:

Webservice 1: subset of access, lower privileges and security constraints

Webservice 2: higher privileges

```
<sws:dynamic-wsdl id="spml-readonly" 
    portTypeName="SpmlReadOnlyService" 
    locationUri="SpmlReadOnly">
    <sws:xsd location="/WEB-INF/xsd/spml/pstc_spmlv2_core.xsd"/>
</sws:dynamic-wsdl>

<sws:dynamic-wsdl id="spml-crud" 
    portTypeName="SpmlCrudService" 
    locationUri="SpmlCrud">
    <sws:xsd location="/WEB-INF/xsd/spml/pstc_spmlv2_core.xsd"/>
    <sws:xsd location="/WEB-INF/xsd/spml/pstc_spmlv2_search.xsd"/>
    <sws:xsd location="/WEB-INF/xsd/spml/pstc_spmlv2_batch.xsd"/>
</sws:dynamic-wsdl>
```

Now since both wsdls are based off of the same xsds, the 'namespace' and 'localPart" of the requests come across the wire identical, regardless of which web service i'm hitting (/SpmlReadOnly or /SpmlCrud).

Therefore, that's ruling out the deprecated PayloadRootQNameEndpointMapping since the localPart and namespace are still identical, etc,... and my current config simply routes the requests to the same endpoint method handler, and i have no way of distinguishing which web service was called:

```
    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "lookupRequest")
    @ResponsePayload
    public Source handleLookupRequest(SoapMessage message) throws Exception {
        ...
    }
```

Is what I'm able to do even possible?  If the xsd's are shared and have identical namespaces at the root of the schema, and the same localPart method requests, will there ever be a way to distinguish between them and map to two different end points?  Any information on this would be useful!  I'm hoping i don't have to set up two separate .wars and deploy them separately with their own code bases on a server!

Thanks,
Damian

Answer (score 6):

You need something that combines `URI` and `PayloadRoot` mapping. Unfortunately Spring-Ws doesn't have something like this. But because it's very extensible it's really easy to achieve this.

**TL;DR**

See [This branch at GitHub](https://github.com/grgrzybek/spring-forum-help/tree/so-12369701) for working example

**Details**

You need to create mapping of combined URI+QName to `org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.MethodEndpoint` instances. Also you should minimize the code which would duplicate existing Spring-Ws functions.

So 1) You need to explicitly configure Spring-Ws annotations without using `<sws:annotation-driven />`:

This is your requirement (with my schemas):

```
<ws:dynamic-wsdl id="spml-readonly" portTypeName="SpmlReadOnlyService" locationUri="SpmlReadOnly">
    <ws:xsd location="classpath:springws/model/schema.xsd" />
</ws:dynamic-wsdl>

<ws:dynamic-wsdl id="spml-crud" portTypeName="SpmlCrudService" locationUri="SpmlCrud">
    <ws:xsd location="classpath:springws/model/schema.xsd" />
    <ws:xsd location="classpath:springws/model/schema2.xsd" />
</ws:dynamic-wsdl>
```

This is all you need to do by hand which normally is configured by `<sws:annotation-driven />` (one adapter with one JAXB marshaller):

```
<bean class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter">
    <property name="methodArgumentResolvers">
        <list>
            <ref local="marshallingPayloadMethodProcessor"/>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="methodReturnValueHandlers">
        <list>
            <ref local="marshallingPayloadMethodProcessor"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="marshallingPayloadMethodProcessor" class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.MarshallingPayloadMethodProcessor">
    <property name="marshaller" ref="marshaller" />
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="marshaller" />
</bean>

<bean id="marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="contextPaths">
        <list>
            <value>springws.model</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

This is custom mapping:

```
<bean class="springws.PathAndPayloadRootAnnotationEndpointMapping" />
```

And 2) You should create your own mapping

```
public class PathAndPayloadRootAnnotationEndpointMapping extends PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping
{
    @Override
    protected QName getLookupKeyForMessage(MessageContext messageContext) throws Exception
    {
        String urlPart = "";
        QName payloadRootPart = super.getLookupKeyForMessage(messageContext);

        TransportContext transportContext = TransportContextHolder.getTransportContext();
        if (transportContext != null) {
            WebServiceConnection connection = transportContext.getConnection();
            if (connection != null && connection instanceof HttpServletConnection) {
                String requestURI = ((HttpServletConnection)connection).getHttpServletRequest().getRequestURI();
                String contextPath = ((HttpServletConnection)connection).getHttpServletRequest().getContextPath();
                urlPart = requestURI.substring(contextPath.length());
            }
        }

        return new QName(payloadRootPart.getNamespaceURI(), urlPart + "/" + payloadRootPart.getLocalPart());
    }

    @Override
    protected List<QName> getLookupKeysForMethod(Method method)
    {
        List<QName> result = new ArrayList<QName>();
        RequestMapping rm = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(method.getDeclaringClass(), RequestMapping.class);
        String urlPart = rm == null || rm.value().length != 1 ? "" : rm.value()[0];
        List<QName> methodPart = super.getLookupKeysForMethod(method);
        for (QName qName : methodPart) {
            result.add(new QName(qName.getNamespaceURI(), urlPart + "/" + qName.getLocalPart()));
        }
        return result;
    }   
}
```

which extends `org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping`. And all it does is extending the *keys* (QNames of payload root elements) of messages with the information extracted from the endpoint URI. I've used Spring's `@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping` annotation for that, but someone thinking it's a hack may create his/her own annotation.

So for endpoint like this:

```
@org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.Endpoint
@RequestMapping("/ws/SpmlReadOnly")
public class Endpoint1
{
    @ResponsePayload
    @PayloadRoot(namespace = "urn:test", localPart = "method1Request")
    public Response2 method(@RequestPayload Request1 request) throws Exception
    {
        return new Response2("e1 m1");
    }
}
```

the key is not:

```
namespace = urn:test
localName = method1Request
```

but this:

```
namespace = urn:test
localName = /ws/SpmlReadOnly/method1Request
```

The `protected QName getLookupKeyForMessage(MessageContext messageContext)` method ensures that the mapping URI is independent of the WAR context, the application is deployed at.

Comment: You now need to override `getLookupKeysForMethod`, not `getLookupKeyForMethod`.