# how to write multiple endpoint for request with identical namespace and local part using spring WS?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-ws

This is my sample code

```
@Endpoint
public class NotificationEndPoint {

    private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound";


    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "notifications")
    @SoapAction("Events")
    @ResponsePayload
    public NotificationsResponse handleEventRequest(@RequestPayload Notifications notificationsRequest) throws Exception {}

}
```

Comment: If they are really the same you cannot, there must be something different else it isn't possible to identify which method to execute.

Answer (score 0):

i am able to find a similar question which is a bit too tricky to execute but i ll try. anyone looking for similar issue can try this out.

[How can i have two separate web services with identical name space and local name requests be routed to different end points?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12369701/how-can-i-have-two-separate-web-services-with-identical-name-space-and-local-nam)